# Getting page margins of a Word document using OpenXML

Tags: ms-word, openxml

Tried different version of word documents and different page margins in them, but nothing I found on the web did the job.
Here's my attempt at reading page margins from a `.docx` file.

```cs
var document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(sourceDocxPath, true);
var myMargins = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.GetFirstChild<PageMargin>();
// always null
```

Answer (score 0):

In the truest programmer fashion, I figured out the answer 5 minutes after posting

```cs
var leftMargin = document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body
    .GetFirstChild<SectionProperties>()
    .GetFirstChild<PageMargin>().Left;
```

I figured it out by inspecting the outerXml of the document and seeing where things are positioned.

Comment: Paragraph indents are often as important as page margins in Word documents. They may be contained in paragraph styles.